# Commandline parameters to send to user via Trillian

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, trillian

How do you make a shortcut to send to a user via Trillian?

Something like `trillian.exe /sendto:username`

Comment: This is the "related" answer I found so far, but I would like to try some shortcuts file, etc http://help.trillian.im/discussions/windows/303-can-you-send-a-trillian-message-from-the-windows-command-line

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do it via a shortcut? Trillian's automation features are pretty flexible.

Comment: Hi Dracs, can you point me to a documentation to it?